# Error of "document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object"

Tags: javascript, object, null

```js
for(var i=0;i<100;i++) {
var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode("This is just dummy data...but a very long one!!!.");
para.appendChild(node);
var element = document.getElementById("main");
element.appendChild(para);
}
```

```css
<html>
<head>
<title>Experiment -II</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="exp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="main">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I worte the code and tried but i get the error 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object' even though i think object is not null.

Why am i getting this? Is it because i have left the "main" section empty?

Comment: Code looks and works fine http://jsfiddle.net/ktggtsas/

Comment: @imbondbaby — You moved the code into an onload event handler function.

Comment: @imbondbaby-jsfiddle.net/ktggtsas actually correct the mistake i made.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your script is being run before the `<div>` has loaded.

Move your script to the bottom of the document to ensure the element has been loaded, or use a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler.